# DNS Propagation mobile carrier / home ISP

Tags: domains, dns

I just bought a domain and pointed it to the Tumblr IP address to use it as a custom domain. Tumblr says my domain isn't pointed to Tumblr. When I go to the page through my home internet connection it doesn't work, but when I try it over 3G on my phone I'm redirected to Tumblr. Why?

Comment: How long have you waited? It could take several hours to propagate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're curious to see your propagation, visit https://www.whatsmydns.net/ and enter your domain to see where it's checking in on various DNS servers.

Your mobile phone is a different network than your home computer and is using different DNS servers.

You can also try flushing your DNS on your computer to see if that's a culprit: https://www.whatsmydns.net/flush-dns.html